# Plupload - how to open more than one time and refresh the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**js:**

```
$(".butAnexarDoc").live("click", function(){
    $("#anexarArquivos").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes        : 'html5,html4',
        url             : 'js/plupload/examples/upload.php',
        max_file_size   : '1000mb',
        max_file_count  : 20, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
        chunk_size      : '1mb',
        unique_names    : false,
        multiple_queues : true
    });
});
```

ok, first time work perfect, but if i click in a diferent place to open again, the list its not been reloaded.

its always the same, to reload the list i need to refresh the page.

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved:

```
$(".butAnexarDoc").live("click", function(){
     $("#anexarArquivos").plupload({
         // General settings
             runtimes        : 'html5,html4',
             url             : 'js/plupload/examples/upload.php',
             max_file_size   : '1000mb',
             max_file_count  : 20, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
             chunk_size      : '1mb',
             unique_names    : false,
             multiple_queues : true
     });

     // set to getUploader
     var uploader = $('#anexarArquivos').plupload('getUploader');
     // use splice to clean the list
     uploader.splice();
});
```